# Exel/Word documents locked/read-only when going offline

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

We have a number of users on Windows 8 who have an issue with files locking when going offline.

The main sceneario is below:

- Windows 8 laptop connected to LAN on docking station
- Excel / Word document is opened
- Laptop is removed from docking station
- Document becomes read-only and does not allow to save once connected to either LAN/WLAN

It would be helpful to receive some advise or explaination to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: That kind of situation has been going on way longer than just Windows 8 and wireless networking. I suggest adding a generic "Windows" tag to the question instead of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

When Office (and most similar programs) open a file, they leave a small, temporary, hidden "lock" file beside it. This file generally starts with a `~` and has a few lines inside it saying who opened the file and when. When Office finishes with a file, it saves the changes and removes the lock file.

However, if Office is not connected to the network at the time you close the file, the laptop will not have access to the lock file and nobody will be able to edit the file.

The solution is to [show hidden files](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-7/) and then delete the file that begins with the same name, but has a `~` at the start. Make sure that nobody is actually using the file first or you will end up with version conflicts.